# How can I extract text after the text id= in the example below in Excel?

Tags: excel

I have a list of 1000 values like an example below and I need to extract text after the text id=. The desired result is 1421500 in the following case.

```
*New Record Added, Row 6, Key=, new object id=1421500*
```

Comment: Look into [`FIND`](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/find-findb-functions-c7912941-af2a-4bdf-a553-d0d89b0a0628) and [`MID`](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/mid-midb-functions-d5f9e25c-d7d6-472e-b568-4ecb12433028)

Comment: Would it always be at the end of your string? Would it always be a number you are interested in? What have you tried?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that text is in A1, you could use:

```
=MID(A1,SEARCH("id=",A1)+3,len(A1))
```

and then copy down as necessary. If the asterisks are part of the cell, you can remove them using:

```
=SUBSTITUTE(MID(A1,SEARCH("id=",A1)+3,LEN(A1)),"*","")
```